# how to get <td> value from the closest different <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the third  text from the nearest `<tr>` that contains only a specified text in one of the `<td>` (in this case, "cat"), when clicked certain click events.
Below is my example table, and what I'm trying to get is, whenever "click1 or 2 or 3" is clicked, the third `<td>` text from the closest/previous `<tr>` that has "cat"
text.

```html
<table class="animals">
    <tr>
        <td> cat </td>
        <td> dog </td>
        <td> tiger </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> dog-1 </td>
        <td> dog-2 </td>
        <td> dog-3 </td>
        <td> <a href="#" class="drop">click1</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> cat </td>
        <td> mouse </td>
        <td> horse </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> lion </td>
        <td> zebra </td>
        <td> camel </td>
        <td> <a href="#" class="drop">click2</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> goat </td>
        <td> cow </td>
        <td> sheep </td>
        <td> <a href="#" class="drop">click3</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If **"click1"** is clicked, it should only get **tiger** from the closest(preceding) `<tr>`. And if **"click2"**, or **"click3"** is clicked, it should only get **horse**. My code is giving me both "tiger" and "horse" whichever one is clicked.

```
$('.drop').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:contains("cat")').find('td:eq(2)').text();  
  alert(val);}
);
```

Any help to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/5S5Pn/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr:contains("cat"):lt('+$(this).closest('tr').index()+'):last').find('td:eq(2)').text();
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5S5Pn/3/

Comment: Note that I'm really not convinced that this is actually the most efficient way of doing that, but, hey, it works.

Comment: this really works..but like you said, I wonder if there is other efficient ways...really good job! thanks though! will be using it for now ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
$('.drop').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('td:eq(2)').text();
    alert(val);  
});
```

It's not pretty though.  Very tightly tied to your HTML layout.  You may want to add an id or class with an index to each tr tag.

Comment: actually @jcaron's answer is better.  Still, you probably don't want to have your javascript so dependent on your html layout.  Very fragile.